# mysql MEDIUMTEXT performance

Tags: mysql

I want to save very long text like base64(image) encoded string into mysql table.

in this case, is it slow to execute query(select, insert, update, delete)?

```
select * from A where index = x

table A

column index

column base64String <-- MEDIUMTEXT type
```

Answer (score 1):

No not at all, depends on how you are fetching the data not on the size or type of the data. IF you store only the file name of the image file and fetch image from a path might be faster because you can cache those files. But When you store file in base64 encoded please use **blob** data type in mysql.

I dont have any performance issue with storing file in base64, I am using blob as a mysql datatype for the image encoded data. Slow and faster again depends on your complexity of your query and depends on consumer that how your DB consumer gonna consume the data. There are different mechanism for optimization for consuming data from DB but as soon as I store my user's profile image on DB I use Blob as a data type.